# BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2 resources

Tags: resources, biztalk, esb-toolkit-2.0

I am a BTS dev with four years experience implementing "classic" BTS solutions.

I have to do a surprise presentation tomorrow on the ESB toolkit 2. Don't ask why. I would like to be as prepared as possible. I am looking for resources which can be quickly assimilated. Ideally (in rough order of importance):

1. A technical overview of the main moving parts
2. A few of the implementation details, descriptions of itineraries, resolvers, on-ramps etc.
3. Installation and deployment.

Any swift help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, that went pretty terribly. But thanks to @Derek Beattie for his help. With a couple more days I could have nailed this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're familiar with the picture in the Pro BizTalk 2009 book the [ESB poster](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=11976) might help you translate some of that info.

Here are some resources:

(obvious) [ESB 2.1 on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd876606)

The [Pro BizTalk 2009 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219815) has a chapter in it on ESB with sections:

- BizTalk and the ESB Concept
- The Architecture
- The Functional Components
- Working with Itineraries
- Using the Toolkit
- Summary

Interesting [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/5e5f88f4-858e-4e00-b957-f840b41b9650) where Richard Seroter posts some info. (author of [SOA Patterns with BizTalk Server 2009](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847195008))

The ESB Toolkit is large toolkit, it's somewhat unfair to ask you to a presentation on it with so little time to prepare.

In its most simple form, say you have a classic BizTalk implementation that does something simple like pickup a file a directory, drive it through some biz process in an orchestration, transform it, and drop it in another directory.

With the ESB toolkit, you would create an itinerary that gets attached to the message and the itinerary are basically instructions on how/what should happen to it.  So your business process orchestration and maps are de-coupled from the solution.  This also affords you the ability to make changes to the itinerary without re-building the solution.  As the itinerary is being driven, services like the map that is needed to transform your messaged can be "looked up" in the UDDI registry.  All the while the ESB exception management piece can give devs/admins/users a nice web interface into a central location where all your exceptions are sent.  The exception management portal can also provide notifications and alerts for all kinds of exception criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your response Derek.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Derek's answer, I would also suggest readidng up on the ESB Portal and Exception Handling framework components in the Toolkit.  I would say that most of my clients using the ESB components are only using those components, and not itineraries, UDDI, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris